# How to use the word “purge"

Tags: word-usage

I’ve seen the word “purge” used in conjunction with “of” and “from” or being used on its own. However, would it be appropriate to say something like “I purged the information out from my brain?"

Comment: It looks like you're asking whether "purge" plays nicely with "out" (and, by extension, "out from" and maybe "out of") given that it does play nicely with "of" and "from" on their own.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purge+it+from%2Cpurge+it+of%2Cpurge+it+out+of%2Cpurge+it+out+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpurge%20it%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpurge%20it%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpurge%20it%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3):

Here is a definition of this meaning of **purge** from the [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/purge).

> Rid (someone) of an unwanted feeling, memory, or condition

Here are two examples of the usage of **purge** from the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/purge):

> Party leaders have undertaken to purge the party **of** extremists.
>   Hard-liners are expected to be purged **from** the administration.

**of** denotes what you are getting rid of, and **from** denotes where you are taking it from. You could therefore express yourself as follows:

> I purged the information **from** my brain.
>   I purged my brain **of** the information.

Note that the word **out** is not required in either sentence and its usage would sound uneducated.

Comment: How about “I purged the information out *of* my brain?"

Comment: @lightweaver: possible, but why use more words than you need to?

Comment: @lightweaver - "out" really isn't necessary here, because *purge* always means to take something out of something else.  It sounds non-fluent.

Comment: Out is perfectly acceptable and it sounds fluent to me, it adds emphasis to the act of removal.

Comment: `Purge out therefore the old leaven, that ye may be a new lump, as ye are unleavened. For even Christ our passover is sacrificed for us` - 1 Corinthians 5:7

Comment: @SLC: your reference is somewhat dated (KJV:1611). This Ngram indicates that, ever since 1800, usage of **purge the** has been significantly greater than **purge out the**, and that **purge out the** has declined continuously to present, whereas **purge the** has been stable since 1880. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purge+out+the%2C+purge+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpurge%20out%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpurge%20the%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

> I purged the information out from my brain

Yup this is correct.

You can also say:

> A) I purged my brain of information

and

> B) I purged the information from my brain

They all mean the same thing.

A emphasises purging your brain. B emphasises purging the information.

Your original sentence, 'out' is not necessary but it is not incorrect. It just emphasises that the information came *out*.

> **Purge** verb (used with object): `to remove by cleansing or purifying (often followed by away, off, or out`

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/purge) (Taken from Random House Dictionary)

Comment: **out from** is not idiomatic, at least not with **purge**.

Comment: `to remove by cleansing or purifying (often followed by away, off, or out).` from Dictionary.com

Comment: But not by **out from**.

Comment: `And I will purge out from among you the rebels, and them that transgress against me: I will bring them forth out of the country where they sojourn, and they shall not enter into the land of Israel: and ye shall know that I am the LORD.` Ezekiel 20:38

Comment: But we're not talking that way any more.   Would you advise the OP to use "ye"?  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purge+out+from&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpurge%20out%20from%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It's unsurprising that the ngrams are low for an uncommon three word phrase. The alternative is *purged the information out my brain* which sounds incorrect, it needs a modifier such as *of* or *from*. Because *purged* doesn't mean something was taken *out*, you can *purge* a plagued town by killing its infected population. This specifically explains that the information was removed by taking it out.

Comment: "The stubbornness was purged out from him" wants "of", not "from".

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree.

Comment: That's not really how it works. You need to find a few modern English attestations to support your view that "purged {something} *out from*" is standard usage nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

*Purge* means "to remove all unneeded/unwanted items" or "to make empty."

*Purge* is weird because it takes an object, but that object can be the thing X needing items Y removed, or it can be the items Y that need to be removed from X.

*Of* and *from* allow us to tell which is which.

> I purged the file of old data.  (We're removing old data from the file.)
>
> I purged old data from the file.  (We're still removing old data from the file.)

---

> However, would it be appropriate to say something like “I purged the information out from my brain?"

*Out* isn't technically needed since *purge* already means "to remove", which means the unwanted items will be outside of what they are removed from already, but it can be there for emphasis if desired.  By emphasizing, you are creating the impression that it took much effort to purge the information from your brain, for example.

Comment: Does this imply that the "out" of "purge out" does *not* function like the "out" of "take out"?  I still have to wonder whether "purge out the tank" or "purge out the impurities" functions the same as "take out the garbage", which is itself distinct from "take the garbage"

Comment: Not really.  *Take out* means/impiles *to carry* whereas *purge out* doesn't.  But you can see how a speaker/writer might use *purge out* in a related sense, e.g. "purge out the impurities" - impurities are a form of trash, but it does not mean physically carrying anything out like "take out the trash" does.

Comment: Granted, the object of "take" is always the thing removed while the object of "purge" is sometimes the thing removed and sometimes the container.  On its own, "take" resembles "acquire".  "Take out" resembles "remove".  Neither needs to resemble "accompany", but either may.  I'm just trying to verify that you see no semantic difference between "purge" and "purge out" by comparing it to the clear semantic difference between "take" and "take out".

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan, you can "take out information" and you can also "take in information": the qualifier is necessary. You cannot "purge in information", so the **out** is redundant with **purge**.

Comment: One might clear a room, one might clear a room out, but I doubt that anyone might clear a room in.  It doesn't seem that every use of "out" is paired with a use of "in".  The sense of clearing a room can be limited to one's own presence, while the sense of clearing a room *out* cannot.    The lack of a contrasting "in" isn't sufficient to label the "out" as redundant or uninformative.